# Swift: `["one": nil] as [String: Any]` works, why?

Tags: ios, swift, nullable

```
func logEvent(events: [String: Any]) {
  print(events);
}

let eventProperties: [String: Any?] = [
  "one": nil,
  "two": "2"
]

logEvent(events: eventProperties as [String: Any])
```

If I change `let eventProperties: [String: Any?]` to `let eventProperties: [String: Any]` I get error that makes sense. But why the code above works?

```
'nil' is not compatible with expected dictionary value type 'Any'
  "one": nil,
```

Comment: Not related to your question but why would you set a dictionary key to nil instead of simply omitting it?

Comment: For example when I send data to analytics some destinations require exact keys to map the data to correct table, when I omit a key the data goes to a different table and it's very hard to connect them later

Answer (score 5):

Every type is a subtype of `Any`. That includes every kind of `Optional` including `Optional<Any>`. So you can definitely convert `[String: Any?]` into `[String: Any]` because `Any?` is a kind of `Any`.

On the other hand, the literal `nil` only applies to `Optional`, so `let x: Any = nil` isn't valid. `Any` is not `Optional`.

This mess is one key reason you should avoid `Any`, and you should strongly avoid `Any?`. When coupled with Optional-promotion (the fact that a type can be promoted to the Optional of itself when assigned), Any-types quickly become a thicket of confusing errors and subtle behaviors. A very common problem is to wind up with `Any??` values like `.some(nil)`, which is not itself nil. Avoid this if at all possible.

For your logging problem, `[String: Any]` may be fine. I've used it myself very effectively. But don't create `[String: Any?]` dictionaries. If you really need a nil placeholder you can include, then do it this way:

```
let anyNil = Any?.none as Any 

let eventProperties: [String: Any] = [
    "one": anyNil,
    "two": "2"
]
```

(But I'd still avoid this if you possibly can.)